# Conditional Reference Paths Based on Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a set of solutions that are organized like this...

```
Master Solution
   - Proj A          
   - Proj B
   - Proj X
   - Proj Y

SolutionAB
   - Proj A
   - Proj B

SolutionXY
   - Proj X
   - Proj Y
```

Dependencies

```
Proj A & B => Proj X & Y
```

What i need is to have MasterSolution look at local project references, and SolutionAB look at a totally arbritrary location for the same dlls.  I can make any changes I need to the `.proj` files, but am limited in my ability to move projects around.  These are just the limitations I have to work with.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with imported property files.  Since references are in the project file, you can move them, or move properties used by them, to a separate .props file.

In separate .props file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SomeAssemblyFolder
    Condition="'$(SolutionName)' == 'Master'">PathTo/Master</SomeAssemblyFolder>
  <SomeAssemblyFolder
    Condition="'$(SolutionName)' == 'AB'">PathTo/AB</SomeAssemblyFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In the project files

```
<Reference Include="SomeAssembly">
  <HintPath>$(SomeAssemblyFolder)\SomeAssembly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I guess you could just duplicate the property definition in every project file if you wanted, but I'd move it to an import.  If you need to build from the command line, or from other solution files remember to supply a reasonable default, or supply a discriminating property on the command line.

Comment: Could you provide more info on your answer on how to create a separate .props file and import .props file in C# projects, or at least links to something that shows this.

Comment: I tried a separate props file using your example in your answer, for some reason the csproj will not pick up the path in the props file even though the imports works and throws no errors, if I put the property group with the shared location in the csproj file it then works, I don't understand why the value is not being picked up from the imported props file.

Comment: This does work I had the path pointed at the wrong import file.

Answer (score 0):

Library references are stored in the project files. Since the projects are shared between the solutions, I don't think there is a simple way to do this.

Any reason the projects can't always look in the arbitrary location for the files?

Comment: yeah, its hard to work with arbritrary dlls when you really just want to work with projects, and at the same time, other people depend on the shared dlls, so you have to leave them in a readonly state on the file system.  Thats just how they do it where i work.